# proof involving rational number

Tags: rational-numbers, geometric-progressions

Show that a real number $q$ is rational if and only if there are three distinct integers, $n_1, n_2, n_3$, such that $q + n_1, q + n_2, q + n_3$ forms a geometric progression.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Edit your question to provide that information and you will probably get some help.

Comment: I tried equating a=q+n1, ar=q+n2 and ar^2=q+n3 Not sure how to link this to rational numbers, or whether to prove by contradiction? Stuck on where to start

Comment: @JoeBlack I suggest proving the $\implies$ direction first. Letting $q = \frac{a}{b}$ should get you started.

Comment: Hint:  In a three-term geometric progression, the square of the middle term is the product of the outer terms.

Comment: How would you say algebraically that the $n$'s are a geometric progression? (And your former comment should have been an edit to the question, not a comment. When you do that now you will see how to format the mathematics, since someone has done that for you.)

Answer (score 1):

First, suppose $q$ is a rational number, so that $q=m/n$ where $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then let $n_1=0,n_2 = mn, n_3 = 2mn+mn^3$.

Conversely, suppose we have such $n_1,n_2,n_3$. Then 
$$\frac{q+n_3}{q+n_2}=\frac{q+n_2}{q+n_1}$$
$$\implies (n_1+n_3)q+n_1n_3 = 2n_2q+n_2^2$$
$$\implies q = \frac{n_2^2-n_1n_3}{n_1+n_3-2n_2}$$
(noting that $n_1+n_3\neq 2n_2$)

Comment: For some reason, the **IF** part was easier for me...

Comment: It's more straightforward, arriving at my values for the $n_i$ took a bit of messing around until I got lucky.

Comment: +1 for this correct answer, but I'd rather you waited to post it or provided just some hints so the OP could learn more about how to attack things like this himself.

Answer (score 0):

## IF

Assume that $q+n_1$, $q+n_2$, and $q+n_3$ form a geometric progression.

Then, $(q+n_2)^2 = (q+n_1)(q+n_3)$.

Expanding and cancelling: $2n_2q+n_2^2 = (n_1+n_3)q+n_1n_3$.

Rearranging: $q=\dfrac{n_2^2-n_1n_3}{n_1+n_3-2n_2}$, hence $q$ is rational.

---

If $n_1+n_3-2n_2=0$, i.e. $2n_2=n_1+n_3$, then we have $n_2^2 = n_1n_3$, then $(2n_2)^2=4n_1n_3$, then $(n_1+n_3)^2-4n_1n_3=0$, then $(n_1-n_3)^2=0$, meaning that $n_1=n_3$, a contradiction.

---

## ONLY IF

See the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

let $$a_1=q+n_1$$,$$a_2=(q+n_1)x$$ and $$a_3=(q+n_1)x^2$$
eliminating the $x$ we obtain $$q+n_3=(q+n_1)\left(\frac{q+n_2}{q+n_1}\right)^2$$
and from hier we get:$$q=\left(\frac{n_2^2-n_1n_2}{n_1+n_3-2n_2}\right)$$
and this is surely rational.